# Как выполнить операции над одномерным массивом и вывести результаты

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

Задан массив

```
A1,1 
A1,2 
A1,3
A1,4
A1,5
A1,6
...
A1,n
```

Нужно вывести

```
A1,2-A1,1      
A1,3-A1,1   A1,3-A1,2      
A1,4-A1,1   A1,4-A1,2   A1,4-A1,3     
A1,5-A1,1   A1,5-A1,2   A1,5-A1,3   A1,5-A1,4     
A1,6-A1,1   A1,6-A1,2   A1,6-A1,3   A1,6-A1,4   A1,6-A1,5      
...         ...         ...         ...         ...          ...
A1,n-A1,1   A1,n-A1,2   A1,n-A1,3   A1,n-A1,4   A1,n-A1,5    A1,n-A1,n-1
```

**Мой алгоритм**

```
 ls = list(range(1, 6))
 res = []
      for i, item in enumerate(ls):
         buf = [item1 - item for item1 in ls[i+1:]]
         res.append(buf)

 for s in range(len(ls)-1):
      print(res[s])
```

**Получаю**

*Выводит данные в горизонтальной развертке*

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2]
 [1]
```

*вместо вертикальной*

```
 [1]
 [2] [1]
 [3] [2] [1]
 [4] [3] [2] [1]
```

*но это не страшно при работе с массивам, так что иду дальше*

*Вместо*

```
 ls = list(range(1, 6))
```

*который приводился для тестирования работоспособности цикла я заношу данные из файла*

*В этом случая я импортирую значения как **str***

```
 with open('Test3.csv') as f:
      ls = f.read()

 res = []
 for i, item in enumerate(ls):
     buf = [item1 - item for item1 in ls[i+1:]]
     res.append(buf)

 for s in range(len(ls)-1):
     print(res[s])
```

*Пытался также так*

*В этом случая я импортирую значения как **list***

```
 ls = open('Test3.csv').readlines()
      res = []

 for i, item in enumerate(ls):
      buf = [item1 - item for item1 in ls[i+1:]]
      res.append(buf)

 for s in range(len(ls)-1):
      print(res[s])
```

**Выдается одна и та же ошибка**
*unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'*

Как я понимаю эту ошибку, для работы цикла (for...) необходимы integer значения, чтобы можно было производить ариф.операцию внутри цикла

Мне только понять как митигировать эту ошибку и все

**УРАА** получилось

```
 ls = open('Test3.csv').readlines()
 res = []

     for i, item in enumerate(ls):
         buf = [int(item1) - int(item) for item1 in ls[i+1:]]
         res.append(buf)

 for s in range(len(ls)-1):
     print(res[s])
```

Comment: это цифровые значения...элемент матрицы                                          A1,1-некое числовое значение и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял условие вопроса:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...:

In [2]: a = pd.Series(np.arange(1,6))

In [3]: print(a)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int32

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(len(a)))
   ...:

In [5]: for i in range(len(a)):
   ...:     df[i] = a.shift(i) - a.iloc[i]
   ...:

In [6]: print(df)
   0    1    2    3    4
0  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1 -1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  2  0.0 -2.0  NaN  NaN
3  3  1.0 -1.0 -3.0  NaN
4  4  2.0  0.0 -2.0 -4.0
```

Comment: Столбец **0** посчитался правильно.

Comment: $MaxU     Столбец **0** посчитался правильно. Столбец **1-4** не верно.  **Столбец 0** считается так: (2-1=1), (3-1=2), (4-1=3), (5-1=4). **В столбце 1** правильные расчеты начинаются с пересечения строчки 3 и столбца 1, т.е. они смещены на 2 строчки вниз. **В столбце 2** расчеты смещены на 3 строчки вниз и т.д.

Comment: @UnoMan, приведите в вопросе ожидаемый вывод для входного массива: `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: привел пример ожидаемого вывода

Comment: $MaxU   пример приведен в тексте вопроса

Comment: @UnoMan, я не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться - красивого "треугольного" __вывода на экран__ или получить соостветствующий DataFrame, где вместо пробелов будут `NaN` как у меня в ответе или чего-то другого...

Comment: $MaxU частично я реализовал, только не получается перевести алгоритм в боевой режим из обучающегося